# WatchKit Modal Sheet top right "Done" button

Tags: watchkit

This has been asked in 2015 and 2016 but maybe WatchOS 5 brings a change to this:

When presenting dictation input, the user can click 'cancel' as well as 'done'. I would like to use this for a modal sheet in my app as well. Unfortunately I can't find any API on how to create this button. Is this private API?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean (right picture) https://mikebluestein.com/2015/05/02/voice-dictation-with-watchkit-and-xamarin/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, Apple hasn't made a public API for that, and the Done button in the question article's screenshot is unique to Apple's own `presentTextInputController(withSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:)`. I'd file a suggestion with your developer account in Bug Reporter → watchOS + SDK → WatchKit.

If you only need a Done button and not a Cancel button as well, what you could do is present a modal and change the top left title text from away from the default "Cancel" to "Done".

Comment: The latter is a really good idea. Do you know whether this will pass App Review?

Comment: It definitely will. I just revisited the watchOS Human Interface Guidelines, and the example Apple themselves use for customizing the modal title is with Done.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/modal-sheets/

Comment: Totally missed this sentence on there, thank you Austin